Custom time deserialization with Jackson
I need to handle an older set of data files, where among other infos, a local data time was serialized to the form
"timeOfAcquisition":[2024,8,13,9,49,52,662000000]
Younger files will additionally contain information about the time zone where the data was created.
In my application, I need to deserialize the local date time with Jackson into a ZonedDateTime. This application needs to handle either case, with or without time zone information, in order to use the older files as well. For the older files, a certain time zone can be assumed although it is not included in the files since I know where the data was generated. The example above corresponds to
2024-08-13T09:49:52.662+01:00

since the time zone where the JSON originates was at UTC offset +01:00 on this date.
How would I create a custom deserializer for Jackson for this?

662000000 >> .662+0100 How does that work?

Too much missing information. How do you find the offset is +1? The input has no such information. How to find out the correct time zone? The input has no such information and desired output has no timezone either, only offset.

Once you've worked out to answer my question, you would be able to use OffsetDateTime but not ZonedDateTime as there is no geographical timezone info, as @Chaosfire said

Right now the time zone is an assumption, since I know where the data was generated. The format of the serialized data will soon be changed to contain the time zone infos. In this problem, I have to handle the older data, where the time zone was not yet included.

@g00se 662000000 must be nanosecond of second. So the example denotes 52,662 seconds past 9:49, and as tabina says, time zone is not included (nor UTC offset).

I believe SO is more about helping you fix code you have already written, rather than posting sample code that shows how to achieve something. So have you written any code? Or are you saying that you have no idea how to write code that creates a LocalDateTime from a string (for example 2024,8,13,9,49,52,662000000) using Jackson?

So I suggest that you need something like LocalDateTime.of(2024, 8, 13, 9, 49, 52, 662000000) .atZone(yourAssumedZoneId).

@Abra There are some successful open-ended questions on Stack Overflow (not that many). However, some research is always expected, and I don’t see much sign of that in the question asked here. And research would often, but not always, include an attempt at writing code.

@tabina You could create a custom deserializer. This is likely to be the quickest and most efficient solution.

@Bademeister tabina is already asking How would I create a custom deserializer ...? So I can’t see you are providing anything?

@tabina Can you please show an example of JSON with and without TimeZone.

@Chaosfire While some of the information has been added later, you still have got a point: It’s unclear whether the OP really needs an OffsetDateTime such as 2024-08-13T09:49:52.662+01:00 or a ZonedDateTime such as 2024-08-13T09:49:52.662+01:00[Europe/Dublin] for example. It might even be unclear to the OP too?


How would I create a custom deserializer for Jackson for this?

Here’s to get you started.
public class ModelDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyModel> {
    private static final ZoneId assumedZoneId = ZoneId.of("Pacific/Norfolk");

    public ModelDeserializer() {
        super(MyModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public MyModel deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        ArrayNode array = (ArrayNode) node.get("timeOfAcquisition");
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(array.get(0).asInt(),
                array.get(1).asInt(), array.get(2).asInt(),
                array.get(3).asInt(), array.get(4).asInt(),
                array.get(5).asInt(), array.get(6).asInt());
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        model.timeOfAcquisition = ldt.atZone(assumedZoneId);
        return model;
    }
}

The basic trick is to read the array of numbers from the JSON as an ArrayNode and pass each of the 7 elements as int to LocalDateTime.of(). You will want to add validation that the array has length 7. And substitute the time zone where your JSON comes from. Also I am leaving to you to extend the code to handle the case where time zone is included in the JSON.
I have assumed a model class like this:
public class MyModel {
    public ZonedDateTime timeOfAcquisition;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyModel{timeOfAcquisition=" + timeOfAcquisition + '}';
    }
}

To try the whole thing out:
        String json = """
                {
                    "timeOfAcquisition":[2024,8,13,9,49,52,662000000]
                }""";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(MyModel.class, new ModelDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        MyModel obj = mapper.readValue(json, MyModel.class);
        System.out.println(obj);

Output from this snippet is:
MyModel{timeOfAcquisition=2024-08-13T09:49:52.662+11:00[Pacific/Norfolk]}

ZonedDateTime or OffsetDateTime?
My result includes the time zone identifier (Pacific/Norfolk in my example, I know that you will choose a different one). If you want a result without the time zone (as in 2024-08-13T09:49:52.662+01:00 from your question), you should, all things being equal, prefer an OffsetDateTime over a ZonedDateTime. A IANA time zone, for example Europe/London or Africa/Lagos, represents all historic and known future offsets for that time zone, including but not limited to summer time (DST) transitions. Which is needed if you want to calculate, for example, 12 hours ahead of the given time in that time zone.
